# Best way to create animated hotspots/image maps

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

After a few hours of searching the web I couldn't find much help on this topic. It could be that I wasn't simply coming up with the right search terms.

My question is this: 
What would be the best way of creating animated hotspot areas (that are clickable hyperlinks) on top of a div?

You are probably wondering why I'm asking this. I have a 360* interactive panorama thing going on (created with a jpeg sequence) and I would like to have some clickable hotspots in the panorama. Because the camera is panning, the hotspots have to be animated in order to follow the right onscreen-elements.

Is canvas capable of animating hotspots/links? Or should I look elsewhere for the solution? SVG maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this without canvas, which is problematic anyway because you cannot natively attach event listeners to the individual elements you draw, or SVG.

Create your hotspots as absolutely positioned divs and move them to the appropriate positions for each frame of the panoramic when it is reached using something like the [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this out. And your method of animating AP divs sounds simple enough!